# How to select items in NSOutlineView without NSTreeController?

Tags: cocoa, select, nsoutlineview

I'm using `NSOutlineView` *without* `NSTreeController` and have implemented my own datasource. What is the best way to select an item?
`NSOutlineView` support already `expandItem:` and `collapseItem:`. And I'm missing a handy method like `selectItem:. How can I do it programatically ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remember to look in superclasses when you can't find something. In this case, one of the methods you need comes from NSTableView, which is NSOutlineView's immediate superclass.

The solution is to [get the row index for the item using `rowForItem:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutlineView/rowForItem:), and if it isn't -1 (item not visible/not found), [create an index set with it with `[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexSet/indexSetWithIndex:) and pass that index set to [the `selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:` method](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:).

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the answer. I already know the method selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:. The problem is that NSOutlineView is working with NSIndexPath and not NSIndexSet.

Comment: I don't see a single instance of NSIndexPath in the NSOutlineView documentation. Perhaps you're thinking of NSTreeController, which you're not using. Moreover, an outline view *is* a table view, which means all the table view functionality should work just fine in the outline view.

Comment: Yes I see. To bad that there is no built-in solution which not depends on my datasource. I have to write extra code in my datasource, right?

Comment: No. Those three steps are all you have to do to select a specific item. (Or items, for that matter.)

Comment: I think I need at least the code in my datasource to expand a node if rowForItem: fails.

Comment: cocoafan: You mentioned `expandItem:` in your question. That's a method of the NSOutlineView. I'm not sure whether you can pass it a deeply-nested item, but even if you can't, you can use NSOutlineView's `parentForItem:` to build a stack of the desired item's ancestors, then walk that stack and expand each item in turn.

Answer (score 22):

Here is how I finally ended up. Suggestions and corrections are always welcome.

```
@implementation NSOutlineView (Additions)

- (void)expandParentsOfItem:(id)item {
    while (item != nil) {
        id parent = [self parentForItem: item];
        if (![self isExpandable: parent])
            break;
        if (![self isItemExpanded: parent])
            [self expandItem: parent];
        item = parent;
    }
}

- (void)selectItem:(id)item {
    NSInteger itemIndex = [self rowForItem:item];
    if (itemIndex < 0) {
        [self expandParentsOfItem: item];
        itemIndex = [self rowForItem:item];
        if (itemIndex < 0)
            return;
    }

    [self selectRowIndexes: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: itemIndex] byExtendingSelection: NO];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for these methods. They are incredible useful! In my opinion, this answer is more complete and elaborate than the previously accepted one.

Comment: This is great - how would we do this in swift?

Comment: added a swift answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a `selectItem:` method, but there is an `rowForItem:` method. If you combine that with Peter's advice about using `selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:` above, you should have all the information you need.

If you really wanted to have a method to select an item, which I would recommend calling `setSelectedItem:` for consistency's sake, you could write something like this in a category on `NSOutlineView`

```
- (void)setSelectedItem:(id)item {
    NSInteger itemIndex = [self rowForItem:item];
    if (itemIndex < 0) {
        // You need to decide what happens if the item doesn't exist
        return;
    }

    [self selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:itemIndex] byExtendingSelection:NO];
}
```

I have no idea if this code actually works; I just dashed it off to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

(This is still coming up as a top result on Google)

Swift 4.2:

You need to make sure the parent is expanded first:

```
if let parent = outlineView.parent(myItem){
        mapOutlineView.expandItem(parent)
}


let rowIndex = outlineView.row(forItem: myItem)
        guard rowIndex != -1 else {return}
        outlineView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: rowIndex), byExtendingSelection: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet I used to programmatically select an item in a PXSourceList.

sourceList is a regular PXSouceList object and I wanted to select the second item in the first group of the outline.

> ```
>     NSInteger itemRow = [sourceList rowForItem:[[(SourceListItem *)[sourceListItems objectAtIndex:0] children] objectAtIndex:1]];
>     [sourceList selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:itemRow] byExtendingSelection:YES];
> ```

If you don't know yet, PXSourceList is an excellent replacement for an NSOutlineView if you re looking for itunes/mail style outlines. Pick it up here:
[PxSourceList](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the situation is still the same. As there was a request for a swift version, here's my take. I didn't find the accepted answer to work for me as I think you should interact directly with your data source class rather than extending the NSOutlineView. Annoyingly, the outline won't find rows unless they are expanded which is why it's simpler to use your dataSource. In my case I found that you have to expand the parent's of your items in reverse order, so that you start at the top level and work your way towards the actual item you're trying to expand. I feel like that should be built in, but unless I missed something - it's not.

In this example FileItem is my data source collection item class. It contains a property "parent" which needs to be valid if it is part of the hierarchy displayed.

```
func selectItem(_ item: FileItem, byExtendingSelection: Bool = false) {
    guard let outlineView = outlineView else { return }

    var itemIndex: Int = outlineView.row(forItem: item)

    if itemIndex < 0 {
        var parent: FileItem? = item

        var parents = [FileItem?]()
        while parent != nil {
            parents.append(parent)
            parent = parent?.parent
        }

        let reversedTree = parents.compactMap({$0}).reversed()

        for level in reversedTree {
            outlineView.expandItem(level, expandChildren: false)
        }

        itemIndex = outlineView.row(forItem: item)
        if itemIndex < 0 {
            print("Didn't find", item)
            return
        }
    }

    print("Expanding row", itemIndex)

    outlineView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: itemIndex), byExtendingSelection: byExtendingSelection)
    outlineView.scrollRowToVisible(itemIndex)
}
```

Comment: I disagree. Expanding items is a trait of the view, and _should_ be handled by the outlineView; it has nothing to do with the model. You're just duplicating code the outlineView will have to perform anyway.

Comment: do you have an example of how you do it?

Comment: See the answer I posted above - it ends up more or less in the same place without the index calculation.