# Selection is not getting highlighted in my NSTableView table

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a view-based table in my app. Everything works good except that when I click on the table entry the row/column I get the click and the content of my pick is sent to corresponding method, but the row  is not getting highlighted.

I'm curious why is that, and can the problem be that I have a view-based table, not cell-based?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question here thanks to Peter Hosey

[How to select items in NSOutlineView without NSTreeController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096768/how-to-select-items-in-nsoutlineview-without-nstreecontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
  - (void)selectRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet 
   *)indexes byExtendingSelection:(BOOL)extend
```

Comment: It will highlight your rows as its tableview method

Answer (score 0):

check whether u have set the empty selection or not. if u didn't set it in code check in nib properties or try by setting this setAllowsEmptySelection:no By default setAllowsEmptySelection is YES

Comment: thank you for your response, I do have empty selection checked in my nib though